# Count how many keys are pressed at the same time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to count how many keys are pressed at the same time? I've come quite far but I get some unwanted behavior when tabbing away from my browser window. If I hold down x number of keys when tabbing away from the browser window and then release the keys in a different window the numKeys array stays the same when I tab back to the browser window. Maybe you can check how many keys are pressed when returning to the browser window or something?

My code so far:

```
var numKeys = [];

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(numKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1){
        numKeys.push(e.keyCode);
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = numKeys.length;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(numKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){
        var index = numKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode);
        if(index > -1){ numKeys.splice(index, 1); }
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = numKeys.length;
});
```

Comment: You could just reset all the keys if the user tabbed out like in the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RwXv9/). There isn't really a way to know what the user does in another window

Comment: I'm grateful to SO for bringing all these crazy ideas ;) Check this out http://jsbin.com/xemegudu/1/edit - 'cause I'm not sure about your goal, and I'm finding so hard to press several keys at (exactly) the same time.

Comment: ... and I expect +1 from you guys at least because I managed to lock up my keyboard trying to make your crazy ideas came true ;))

Comment: @SomeGuy your answer helped me solve my issue. If you put it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanielTovesson Added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem would be to clear the keys pressed when the user leaves the tab. You can use the [`window.onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onblur) event like this:

```
window.onblur = function () {
    numKeys = [];
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RwXv9/).

Note that this solution will not be aware of keys you press in another window. (For example, you press "up" in another window, and then select this window again)

Answer (score 3):

**try this (UPDATE):**

```
var cpt = 0;
var codes = "";
$(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (codes.indexOf(";" + e.keyCode + ";") == -1) {
            cpt++;
            codes += ";" + e.keyCode + ";";
        }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        var tmp = ";" + e.keyCode + ";";
        if (codes.indexOf(tmp) != -1) {
            cpt--;
            var part1 = codes.substring(0,codes.indexOf(tmp));
            var part2 = codes.substring(codes.indexOf(tmp)+tmp.length );
            codes=part1+part2;
        }
    });
});
```

**The new Working ;) link :** [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4N4p3/8/)

Comment: But it just tells how many have been pressed, not the current number. If I press A, S and D and release D, it would still show 3.

Comment: Your jsFiddle isn't related to your snippet :)

Comment: My keyboard is beeping like crazy; +1 even I can't test it with more than four keys (just as I couldn't using my snippet)

Comment: normal keyboards dosn't  support holding more than 3 or 4 keys if you have to hold down more consider to buy an gamer keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it very simple. Idea is to set the `keys` with the object being `event.keyCode` to true on `keydown`, and delete on `keyup`. Then count the instances of `true` in `keys`,

```
var keys = [];
$(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (event) {
        keys[event.keyCode] = true;

        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (keys[i]) count++;
        }
        console.log(count);
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        delete keys[e.keyCode];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to share my snippet mentioned and linked just a few minutes before in the comments above. But, just to make it clear, I'm finding hard to press / accept by the keyboard more than four, maybe five keys at the same time and that's why all these attempts might be useless :)

```
window.onload = function(){

  var a = [];
  var log = document.getElementById("keys");

  document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
    var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if(a.indexOf(keyCode) == -1) a.push(keyCode);
    log.innerHTML = a.length + " | " + a.join();
    return false;
  };  

  document.body.onkeyup = function(event){
    a = [];
    log.innerHTML = a.join();
  };

};
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tigayeyu/1/edit?html,js,output)